# how to listen web browser request for send to server?

Tags: c#, .net, http

i want in my program listen to web browser request to send that to server,then on
server,response this request. but in my client code's can't send request.after 
listener.start() i have this message in exception :"the parameter is incorrect"

```
' try
    {

       // IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.Resolve("192.168.1.2");//GetHostAddresses(string "127.0.0.1");//Resolve("host.contoso.com");
     //   IPAddress ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), port);
        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);
        connectDone.WaitOne();
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();
        listener.Prefixes.Add("http://127.0.0.1: 2000/");

        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("im listening...");
        HttpListenerContext context = listener.GetContext();
        HttpListenerRequest requst= context.Request;

        Send(client,requst.ToString());
        sendDone.WaitOne();`
```

Comment: Try a better approach: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93301/Implementing-a-Multithreaded-HTTP-HTTPS-Debugging

Comment: is Space in  `http://127.0.0.1: 2000/` a typo?

Answer (score 0):

a time ago i wrote a function for that:

```
public string request(string url)
    {
        string responseText = "";
        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        WebHeaderCollection header = response.Headers;

        var encoding = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII;
        using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), encoding))
        {
            responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return responseText;
    }
```

It's not a correction for your code but maybe its usefull for you. Just give your `http://127.0.0.1: 2000/` as the parameter and hopefully you are done.